# Почему socket.io не переставая генерирует новые соединения?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

У меня есть приложение на express, в котором используется socket.io. На серверной стороне каждые 50 миллисекунд генерируется запрос:

```
setInterval(() => {
  io.emit('data', data);
}, 50);
```

На стороне клиента запрос принимается и устанавливается значение для переменной:

```
var list = {};
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  list = data;
});
```

Однако вместо использования 1 постоянного соединения, socket.io генерирует по 6-7 соединений в секунду. Почему это происходит?

[image: Соединения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему socket.io не переставая генерирует новые соединения?

### Предполагаю:

- потому, что ваша серверная реализация не поддерживает `ws`
- что-то неверно настроено
- что-то блокирует `ws` поэтому socket.io переключился на `xhr`

Cмотри на скриншоте:

type - `xhr` (вместо `ws` или `wss`)

### socket.io это не только WS

- https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-websocket-transport-only

> ```
> const socket = io({
>   transports: ['websocket']
> });
>
> // on reconnection, reset the transports option, as the Websocket
> // connection may have failed (caused by proxy, firewall, browser, ...)
> socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
>   socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
> });
> ```

### пример

- https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Вы правы, оказалось, что сервер, на котором работало приложение, не поддерживал ws.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может заключаться в том что версии socket.io-client и socket.io могут не совпадать и из за этого может возникнуть такая проблема. Также распространенная проблема (особенно у новичков) когда устанавливаете не забывайте точку , то есть не socketio , а socket.io. Можете проверить не ошиблись ли вы в package.json